# K8s error: [kube-peers] Could not get peers: Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/nodes": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to K8s.
I setup a cluster with 1 master and 1 worker in Azure. I am using Azure VMs.
I could be able to setup etcd, api server, scheduler etc on master and kubelet, kube=proxy on worker and can fetch nodes using kubectl get nodes  in master.
The nodes are at NotReady state as I was trying to create networking using weavenet.
But the pods are not creating. 1 Pod is created but the other one is throwing error. Upon investigation it looks the kubernetes service has
endpoint which is not reachable from worker node. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Two things: this question belongs on https://ServerFault.com since it is very clearly not about programming, and when you re-ask that question over there, don't use screenshots for textual content since it's hard to read and is not indexed by search engines, limiting the usefulness of your question to others in the same situation

Comment: Looks like firewall issue. Try disabling firewall on both the nodes `sudo systemctl stop firewalld`

Comment: Please avoid using pictures, instead of that please copy output, errors and configuration as text. Can you provide `kubectl describe node <nameNotReadyNode>`? Did you remove taints from master? Did you configure somehow firewall? How did you initialize kubeadm? Did you try other CNIs?

Comment: Thank you confusedgenius, PjoterS, yes it was firewall issue.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comment section, root cause of the issue was related to `Firewall configuration`. After adjusting firewall rules, OP confirmed that it's working.

> Thank you confusedgenius, PjoterS, yes it was firewall issue.

In general `no route to host` indicates that

- The host is unavailable
- Network issues

In this scenario firewall probably blocked traffic from port 443 on the  10.96.0.1 node.

Depends on your OS, you can use preinstalled firewall management tools like [Firewalld](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7)

```
### Temporary disable FirewallD
$ sudo systemctl stop firewalld

### Adding port on firewall
$ sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=port/protocol --permanent.
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

[UFW](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-firewall-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) on `Ubuntu`

```
$ sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

or just `flush iptables` like in [this article](https://imlc.me/how-to-resolve-no-route-to-host-in-kubernetes).

```
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
iptables --flush
iptables -tnat --flush
systemctl start kubelet
systemctl start docker
```